# lerp movement and keyboard movement buttons - fast pressing cause a character stuck in place

Tags: python, pygame

So I decided to add linear interpolation to my rectangle character in pygame. I saw lerp a few days ago and i'm not sure if i'm missing something.

The problem is:
When I move for example right. The velocity interpolate to reach the desired max velocity - (7) or (-7 for left).
When i release the key, the velocity again interpolate, from max velocity to 0, very smooth.
But if i hit the left button, while i'm moving right, the interpolation goes from velocity 7 to 0, making my character stops.

EDIT: This is part of the whole game, I skiped functions like jump and collision detection with the window borders, etc functions. But this code still reproduce the movement I dont want.

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
import datetime
from pygame.locals import *

class Vector(object):
    ''' Performs vector aritmetics
    '''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self, v):
        x = self.x + v.x
        y = self.y + v.y
        return Vector(x, y)

class GroundData(object):
    ''' Ground data structure.
    Creates a ground data structure and her component's.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        # Vectors
        self.position = Vector(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - WINDOWHEIGHT / 3)
        self.size = Vector(WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT-self.position.y)

        # Ground data structure
        self.color = (128, 128, 128) # Gray
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((self.position.x, self.position.y),
                             (self.size.x, self.size.y))
        self.ground = {'shape': self.rect, 'color': self.color}

    def draw(self):
        ''' Draw's the ground shape and color using pygame.draw.rect(...).
        '''
        pygame.draw.rect(WINDOWSURFACE, self.ground['color'],
                                    self.ground['shape'])


class PlayerData(object):
    ''' Player data structure.
    Creates a player data structure and handles few actions.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.ground = GroundData()

        # Vectors
        self.size = Vector(50, 70)
        self.position = Vector(
            15, self.ground.position.y - self.size.y + 1) # + 1 forced collision
        self.velocity = Vector(0, 0)
        self.velocity_goal = Vector(0, 0)
        self.gravity = Vector(0, 3)

        # Player data structure
        self.color = (0, 100, 0) # Dark Green
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((self.position.x, self.position.y),
                                (self.size.x, self.size.y))
        self.player = {'shape': self.rect, 'color': self.color}

    def is_colliding_ground(self):
        ''' Returns true if player shape is colliding with a ground.
        '''
        if self.position.y + self.size.y >= self.ground.position.y:
            return True
        return False

    def approach(self, vel_goal, vel_curr, dt):
        difference = vel_goal - vel_curr
        if difference > dt:
            return vel_curr + dt
        if difference < -dt:
            return vel_curr - dt
        return vel_goal

    def update(self, dt):
        self.velocity.x = self.approach(self.velocity_goal.x,
                                    self.velocity.x, dt * 95)
        # Update position and velocity
        # self.position = self.position.add(self.velocity) * dt
        # If I mult (x, y) by dt I get alot slower.
        self.position = self.position.add(self.velocity)
        self.player['shape'].top = self.position.y
        self.player['shape'].left = self.position.x

    def draw(self):
        ''' Draw's the player shape and color using pygame.draw.rect(...).
        '''
        pygame.draw.rect(WINDOWSURFACE, self.player['color'],
                                    self.player['shape'])


class EventManagement(object):
    ''' Handles keyboard event's.
    Toggles player variables according to the event's.
    '''
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player

    def is_doneloop(self, flag):
        global is_doneloop
        is_doneloop = flag
        return is_doneloop

    def listen(self):
        ''' Toggles player variables according to keyboard/mouse input.
        '''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.is_doneloop(True)

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                    self.player.velocity_goal.x = -7
                if event.key == ord('d'):
                    self.player.velocity_goal.x = 7

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    self.is_doneloop(True)
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                    self.player.velocity_goal.x = 0
                if event.key == ord('d'):
                    self.player.velocity_goal.x = 0

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

WINDOWWIDTH = 900
WINDOWHEIGHT = 500
WINDOWSURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
is_doneloop = False
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 40

def mainloop():
    pygame.init()
    Ground = GroundData()
    Player = PlayerData()
    EventHandle = EventManagement(Player)

    prev_time = 0
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    while not is_doneloop:
        # Get deltaT
        dt = Clock.tick(FPS)
        dt = dt / 1000.0 # Convert milliseconds to seconds
        pygame.display.set_caption('FPS: %.2f' % Clock.get_fps())

        # Handle events
        EventHandle.listen()

        # Update game state
        Player.update(dt)

        # Draw
        WINDOWSURFACE.fill((0, 0, 0)) # Black
        Ground.draw()
        Player.draw()
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainloop()
```

**UPDATE 2 on my Event class**

```
class EventManager(object):
''' Event management.
Listens and handles keyboard and mouse events.
'''
def __init__(self, player):
    self.player = player

    # Player movement flags, according to keyboard/mouse state
    self.is_move_left, self.is_move_right = False, False
    self.is_jump = False

def exit_game(self):
    ''' Closes pygame and sys modules.
    A break statement follows this method to break the mainloop.
    '''
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def listener(self):
    ''' Toggles Player movement flags, according to keyboard/mouse state.
    '''
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            self.exit_game()
            break

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_a:
                self.is_move_left = True
            elif event.key == K_d:
                self.is_move_right = True

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                self.exit_game()
                break
            if event.key == K_a:
                self.is_move_left = False
            elif event.key == K_d:
               self.is_move_right = False

def handler(self):
    ''' Set Player velocity_goal according to movement flags.
    '''
    if self.is_move_left and not self.is_move_right:
        self.player.velocity_goal.x = -self.player.MAX_VELOCITY
    elif self.is_move_right and not self.is_move_left:
        self.player.velocity_goal.x = self.player.MAX_VELOCITY
    elif not self.is_move_left and not self.is_move_right:
        self.player.velocity_goal.x = 0
```

Comment: You talk about hitting left and right buttons but show the code acting upon `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP`.  I am confused, but maybe that confusion goes away if you provide the code more connected to what you describe.

Comment: @Alfe: From the question and the code I would assume that the 'a' key is the Left key and 'd' is the Right one -- and `velocity_goal.x` is changed differently according on whether they are being pressed or released.

Comment: @martineau, Ahh, now I see what I misunderstood here.  Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I think I'd like to see that `self.approach` now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any problem in the code you posted.  So I guess the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Alfe If you put a rect in this code and try to move. Hold down one of the both directional keys to run, now release that key and immediately press the opposite key to run in the opposite direction. The character will stop at 0 velocity. To run again you must release the held down key and press it again. I want to be able to run as smooth as possible without stoping.

Comment: It would be easier to see and (especially) run full code to see how it works and to test modifications.

Comment: I beleive I agree with @furas (and @Alfe), please post a small but runnable piece of code illustrating your problem.

Comment: @martineau I added a runnable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what reaction your rectangle character should have for every possible combination of key/button presses because some are ambiguous, such as when both the Left and Right keys are being held down simultaneously -- so the following modifications (which are only to the `EventManagement.Listen()` method) may not produce exactly the sought-after behavior.

In the revised version, if you hit the left button while moving right, nothing visually occurs until you release the right button, and in a reverse situation the opposite happens. Either way, the velocity changes smoothly.

Essentially what I done is implement the handling of the two velocity keys as an [event-driven finite-state-machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_finite-state_machine) that can be in one of four states representing all the possible combinations of these two keys being in either the up or down position. In addition to that there are 4 different velocity key "events" corresponding to these keys being pressed or released.

The code's a bit longish because it must handle with every possible event in every possible state, but it's not what I would call complicated. It may be possible to shorten it by making it [table-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table-driven), which is an alternative way to implement [finite-state-automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

```
# added constants
LEFT_KEY = K_a
RIGHT_KEY = K_d
LURU, LDRU, LURD, LDRD = range(4)  # velocity states
LD, RD, LU, RU = range(4)  # velocity key events
VEL_EVENTS = {LD, RD, LU, RU}  # all possible velocity key events
MAX_VELOCITY = 200

class EventManagement(object):
    ''' Handles keyboard events.
        Toggles player variables according to the event.
    '''
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player
        self.state = LURU

    def is_doneloop(self, flag):
        global is_doneloop
        is_doneloop = flag
        return is_doneloop

    def listen(self):
        ''' Toggles player variables according to keyboard/mouse input.
        '''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            vel_event = None

            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.is_doneloop(True)
                break

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == LEFT_KEY:
                    vel_event = LD
                elif event.key == RIGHT_KEY:
                    vel_event = RD

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    self.is_doneloop(True)
                    break
                if event.key == LEFT_KEY:
                    vel_event = LU
                elif event.key == RIGHT_KEY:
                    vel_event = RU

            if vel_event in VEL_EVENTS:
                if self.state == LURU:
                    if vel_event == LD:
                        self.player.velocity_goal.x = -MAX_VELOCITY
                        self.state = LDRU
                    elif vel_event == RD:
                        self.player.velocity_goal.x = MAX_VELOCITY
                        self.state = LURD
                elif self.state == LDRU:
                    if vel_event == RD:
                        self.state = LDRD
                    elif vel_event == LU:
                        self.state = LURU
                        self.player.velocity_goal.x = 0
                elif self.state == LURD:
                    if vel_event == LD:
                        self.state = LDRD
                    elif vel_event == RU:
                        self.state = LURU
                        self.player.velocity_goal.x = 0
                elif self.state == LDRD:
                    if vel_event == LU:
                        self.state = LURD
                        self.player.velocity_goal.x = MAX_VELOCITY
                    elif vel_event == RU:
                        self.state = LDRU
                        self.player.velocity_goal.x = -MAX_VELOCITY

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update**

To address the other problem you alluded to in your comments I think you need to do a couple of things. First of all, the commented-out line in `update()`:

```
    # self.position = self.position.add(self.velocity) * dt
```

doesn't work because it is not a proper translation of the C++ version:

```
    box.vecPosition = box.vecPosition + box.vecVelocity * dt;
```

because it adds `position` to `velocity` first, and then multiples the result by `dt`. So to fix it, just make yours the same:

```
    self.position.x = self.position.x + (self.velocity.x * dt)
```

which will allow the quantity `self.velocity.x * dt` to be calculated first via standard [operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), and then that will be added to `self.position.x`.

Even with this modification, changes in speed will be slow. I think this is cause by setting `velocity_goal.x` to too small a value (+/-7 in your code). Instead, use something much bigger like `200`. While you're at it, replace them with a new constant -- something like `MAX_VELOCITY = 200` so you only have to change the value in one place.

Bonus:

While certainly not a requirement, you could simplify/shorten and speed-up your `Vector` class slightly by writing the code this way:

```
class Vector(object):
    ''' Performs vector arithmetic
    '''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self. y = x, y

    def add(self, v):
        return Vector(self.x + v.x, self.y + v.y)

    def mult(self, s):
        return Vector(s * self.x, s * self.y)
```

You could go even further and define `Vector.__add__()`, `Vector.__mul__()`, etc and then be able to use them more naturally.

A final suggestion would be to replace `self.ground = {'shape': self.rect, 'color': self.color}` and `self.player = {'shape': self.rect, 'color': self.color}` with just `self.shape` and `self.color` attributes -- because putting them in a separate dictionary like that offers few advantages and instead just slows down and complicates access to their values.

**Update 2:**

As I mentioned the FSM logic could be made more compact by making it table-driven to remove redundancies -- although doing so also makes it even more abstract and potentially more difficult to understand initially. Here's what I mean:

```
# added constants
LEFT_KEY = K_a
RIGHT_KEY = K_d
LURU, LDRU, LURD, LDRD = range(4)  # velocity states
LD, RD, LU, RU = range(4)  # velocity key events
VEL_EVENTS = {LD, RD, LU, RU}  # every velocity key event value
NEW_VELOCITY_GOAL, NEW_STATE = range(2)  # indices of EVENT_DECISION_TABLE entries
MAX_VELOCITY = 200

# non-None entries represent new velocity_goal and state value for each event for each state
EVENT_DECISION_TABLE = [
# event       LD                     RD                    LU                    RU             # cur state
    [[-MAX_VELOCITY, LDRU], [MAX_VELOCITY, LURD], [None,         None], [None,          None]], # LURU
    [[None,          None], [None,         LDRD], [0,            LURU], [None,          None]], # LDRU
    [[None,          LDRD], [None,         None], [None,         None], [0,             LURU]], # LURD
    [[None,          None], [None,         None], [MAX_VELOCITY, LURD], [-MAX_VELOCITY, LDRU]], # LDRD
]

class EventManagement(object):
    ''' Handles keyboard event's.
    Toggles player variables according to the event's.
    '''
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player
        self.state = LURU

    def is_doneloop(self, flag):
        global is_doneloop
        is_doneloop = flag
        return is_doneloop

    def listen(self):
        ''' Toggles player variables according to keyboard/mouse input.
        '''
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            vel_event = None

            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.is_doneloop(True)
                break
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == LEFT_KEY:
                    vel_event = LD
                elif event.key == RIGHT_KEY:
                    vel_event = RD
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    self.is_doneloop(True)
                    break
                elif event.key == LEFT_KEY:
                    vel_event = LU
                elif event.key == RIGHT_KEY:
                    vel_event = RU

            if vel_event in VEL_EVENTS:
                entry = EVENT_DECISION_TABLE[self.state][vel_event]
                if entry[NEW_VELOCITY_GOAL] is not None:
                    self.player.velocity_goal.x = entry[NEW_VELOCITY_GOAL]
                if entry[NEW_STATE] is not None:
                    self.state = entry[NEW_STATE]

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update 3**

After watching a couple of the [Math for Game Developers](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOpdhYedlD-yCB7WQoHf-My) series videos related to the `PlayerData.approach()` method, I think I now understand what it does (and why its code perplexed me).

The primary cause of my confusion was because its `dt` argument is not a time difference value, which is why it needs to be multiple by yet another magic-number before `PlayerData.update()` calls it. Basically it's delta-velocity per delta-time (also know as acceleration). it's value is related to the maximum velocity, frame per sec (FPS), and time you want the player to take to reach that velocity from zero (average acceleration).

For example, a 40 frames-per-second, the dt`value passed to`PlayerData.update()` will be 0.025 sec, so adding it that to the current velocity will have little effect if the maximum velocity is 80 or 1000, even if you do it 40 times per second.

To understand what it should be requires first defining the object's average acceleration in terms of how long should it take to reach maximum velocity from a standing start. This is just its maximum-velocity / time-to-accelerate. If time is measured in seconds this is the amount of speed-up per second. To find out how much that should be per frame, just divide it by frames-per-second.

Since `dt` is should be a fairly constant for a given FPS, the acceleration-per-frame can be calculated in advance and and stored as another named constant.

Implementing this would require the following changes and additions:

```
# more constants
MAX_VELOCITY = 200
ACCEL_TIME = 1  # secs to accelerate to max velocity (or slow down from it)
AVG_ACCEL = MAX_VELOCITY / float(ACCEL_TIME)  # per sec
ACCEL_PER_FRAME = AVG_ACCEL / FPS

class PlayerData(object):

    ### showing updated methods only

    def approach(self, vel_goal, vel_curr, accel):
        difference = vel_goal - vel_curr
        if difference > accel:
            return vel_curr + accel
        if difference < -accel:
            return vel_curr - accel
        return vel_goal

    def update(self, dt):
        self.velocity.x = self.approach(self.velocity_goal.x,
                                        self.velocity.x, ACCEL_PER_FRAME)
        self.position.x = self.position.x + (self.velocity.x * dt)

        self.player['shape'].top = self.position.y
        self.player['shape'].left = self.position.x
```

Comment: It runs perfectly, and i'm trying to understand how, can you explain the namings of velocity states and key events.

Comment: @dragons: If it runs perfectly and I also answered your follow-on question in the comments, is there some reason you haven't accepted my answer or at least up-voted it? That's how things customarily work here on StackOverflow...

Comment: I have accepted your answer, it solves the problem. But there is 1 more questions and i'm not sure if I must post a new thread. Here it is:
In the update function i added a comment about deltaT, slowing my character alot if i mult by dt. Could you please edit your post and throw few comments what i'm doing wrong. Just a small info that i can then read and research some more.

Comment: Thanks. The deltaT comment mentions `# If I mult (x, y) by dt I get alot slower`, which doesn't really describe what the problem is. What is it -- what are you trying to do but can't?

Comment: The parts of your code that deal with velocity and position changes seems somewhat confused. For example, in the `PlayerData.approach()` method it looks like you're comparing and adding delta velocity and delta time values together which doesn't make much sense to me. You also use some magic numbers like `dt * 95` in places. Perhaps you'd better ask a separate question about the subject.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial series on math for game dev's. Please excuse me for posting this link's from github, but they describe what i'm trying to do, but with python. (The tut's are in C++)
The approach function:
[link]https://github.com/BSVino/MathForGameDevelopers/blob/lerping/math/maths.h
The code that uses the function and a few short functions, similliar to mine:
[link]https://github.com/BSVino/MathForGameDevelopers/blob/lerping/math/maths.h
PS: If this comment is inapropriate, let me know what i should do to keep my account in shape.

Comment: Your comments are acceptable...and after looking into things a little bit more I believe I know what the additional issues are and how to they could be fixed, too. However, there is little motivation for me to add them to this answer because they have different causes -- besides that, you didn't even bother to also up-vote what I've already provided despite the fact that it completely solved the stated question "perfectly", using your own words. As a would-be game designer, I'm surprised you don't understand how incentives work to a better degree.

Comment: I would like to give you an upvote but i needed 15 repp, however they are now 16 (for adding comments?). Be kind enough to give me a directions to look. Vectors and deltaT are pretty new to me. This is a big project for me, becouse it will also have side-scrolling stuff and more. But I can't seem to write the current code in the right way, before i start to add new classes to the file. You got the point.

Comment: I think you got a modest rep boast when I up-voted your question and a little more when you accepted an answer which is shown in your [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2710430/dragons?tab=reputation). Anyway, thanks. I added some suggestions to my answer which may help -- let me know one way or the other.

Comment: Can you write a update function, using the approach function, please.

Comment: Just replace the line that changes `self.position.x` in your update function with the one shown near the middle of my first update after the sentence that starts "So to fix it..."

Comment: It works absolutely how I wanted it... except one thing.
`self.velocity.x = self.approach(self.velocity_goal.x, self.velocity.x, dt * 1000)`

The guy im following the code from uses a value of 65, not to slide very much, but smooth. I use 1000, missmatching to reach his effect.
Also he don't use so much constants and events, making me worry if this approach is good.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, `PlayerData.approach()` doesn't make much sense to me at least in terms of the [classical mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics) I remember. On the other hand, I haven't watched any of the guy's _Math for Game Developers YouTube series_, so maybe there's a method to the madness. Maybe you should ask a another question just about that aspect of things. You can reference your own code and the video's code.

Comment: I have rewrite my Event class with some togglers, it works exactly like I want it (just like yours, but without all those heavy constants). Any reason you didn't do it with toggler bools? From the begining of the game i tend to avoid many constants, so I'm searching for a better approach method that your 3rd update in your post.
You can see my new Event class in the OP

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using name constants -- it's considered a best practice for programming and is certainly better than have a bunch of magic numbers scatter around your code. If their names are meaningful they also make the code more readable and changing the value of any of them only has to be done in one place. There were a lot of them in my initial answer though update 2 because I was using a very abstract finite state machine to implement the behavior desired. Though not a requirement, once in-place it's a relatively easy thing to modify -- to say add up and down keys.

Comment: My third update had nothing to do with event handle, it was address what was being done to make sense of what was really going on with the `update()` and `approach()` methods you were trying to convert from the code in the videos -- and give you an understanding of how maximum velocity and the player's changes in speed were related. The use of constants there was to give meaningful names to the different values being computed and used, as well as make it easy to change them. Perhaps as you gain programming experience, you'll be able to appreciate what I'm trying to say more.